# Updating FK by Child Table Field Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

Given the following records in table B, in that:

```
B.Id | B.CId | B.Name
1 | 1 | "apple"
2 | 2 | "apple"
3 | 1 | "banana"
4 | 2 | "banana"
```

In table A, I have values:

```
A.Id | A.BId | A.CId
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 4 | 1
```

which actually needs to be updated to:

```
A.Id | A.BId | A.CId
1 | 2 | 2
2 | 3 | 1
```

based on the fact that A.CId needs to use A.BId where B.CId matches, and B.Name matches the A.BId's .Name.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense. If all you need is columns from table A, you don't need table B anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SET bid = b.id  --setting the value for bid to the id value in table b
FROM b b JOIN a a on a.cid = b.cid --where the cid cols in each table match
WHERE b.id IN
(SELECT b1.id from b b1 join a a1 on a1.bid = b1.id WHERE b1.name = b.name)  
--and table b's ID is for row with a name value matching when joined on the        
 --foreign key instead of cid
```

Here's a reference to sql update statements involving multiple tables:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1022bbce-3d99-49d1-83a1-75bafa49ac25/tsql-update-statement-with-join

Comment: How do I perform the self-join to match B.Name?

Comment: Updating my answer.  Sounds like you just need to add on a where clause with a subquery

Comment: Ioaoa, the subquery is returning more than one result. also, should the subquery join on a1.CId = b1.CId?

Comment: @CarlSagan  If you have a one to many relationship you need to use 'in' rather than equals. I'll update.   What's important is that the subquery returns the set of records that you intend when you say "and B.Name matches the A.BId's .Name."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `update ... from ...`, see [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177523.aspx).

```
update
    A

set
    BId = B.Id

from
    B

where
    A.CId = B.CId
```

And here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e885/5) as full example.

Comment: Sorry, I added the fact that the updated B.Name needs to matched against A.BId's Name field. Does that make sense?